# Logstash elastic search output custom template not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, logstash-configuration

My **logstash** config is something like the following

```
if "user" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            action => "index"
            index => "user-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            template => '/path/to/elastic-template.json'
            flush_size => 50
        }
}
```

And the json template contains the lines

```
 "fields" : {
                 "{name}" : {"type": "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true, "index_options" : "docs"},
                 "{name}.raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
               }
```

So I assume the **.raw** can be used when searching or generating the visualization.

However, I removed the existing index and rebuild again, I can see the data, but I still cannot find the **.raw** field either Kibana's settings, discover or visualize

How to use the **.raw** field?

Comment: Why didn't you use the Logstash default template? That one does add the `raw` field. Share the full template.

Answer (score 0):

The template you posted isn't even valid JSON. If you want to apply a `raw` field as in `not_analyzed` you have to do it like this:

```
"action" : {
  "type" : "string",
    "fields" : {
      "raw" : {
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

This will create a `action.raw` field.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue. 
I used `ES5.5.1` and `logstash 5.5.1`, below is my template file

```
{
  "template": "access_log",
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "log": {
      "properties":{
        "geoip":{
          "properties":{
             "location" : {
               "type" : "geo_point",
               "index": "false"
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```